# AzureDataFactory-DataFlow-Sink DeltaTable to AzureSQLDatabase with DeltaLake time travel via version

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

The purpose of the exercise is to read a Delta_log file with ADF PipeLine, from which I take the Version and the output from 'Lookup' activity, to store it in Set Variable Activity. Then I want to submit an output from 'Set Variable' as a variable to DataFlow Source and finally to sink the information found based on the Version in a specific table in AzureSQLDatabase.
See the process below:

[image]

Lookup - source dataset is JSON - delta_log file

Set variable - there is a variable deltatableVersion with type Integer, which is set in the 'Set variable' and in the expression builder the content is: @int(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]['version'])

[image: this is the result from 'Set variable']

DataFlow activity configuration:

[image]
[image]

And in the DataFlow we have Source and Sink with Parameter deltatableVersion type Integer.

[image]

In the Source activity the Inline dataset type is Delta and the linked service connection is ADLS Gen2 where there are many parquet files (between 100-200)
[image]

And in the Source Options this is what we have:
[image]

And the Sink type is 'Dataset' - a table in AzureSQLDatabase with the following congfiguration:

[image]

[image]

And I'm getting these errors:

[image]

And this one:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Sink DeltaTable to AzureSQLDatabase with DeltaLake time travel via version

I tried the same and it's working fine for me here are the steps I followed:

- First In data flow I created parameter with name **version_no** and type **Integer**.
  [image]
- Then passed this parameter in Source setting >> **version** as below
  [image]
- In data flow parameters passing value of variable.
  [image]

***The error or issue you are facing is might be caused by the cluster running out of disk space. please retry using an integration runtime with bigger core count and/or memory optimized compute type.***
[image]

If the above does not help, please raise support ticket.

Comment: I created a new integration runtime with a bigger compute size, but now it takes hours without giving an error but I noticed that it doesn't seem to get the data by version. The most recently updated data according to the latest version is megabytes, but when I start to transfer the information I see that it becomes many gigabytes. It seems like they are not synchronizing the data flow parameter with the pipeline variable correctly or something else and it is taking the whole dataset instead the last updated/modified data.